# Jax-rs WriterInterceptor/ ReaderInterceptor never get registered in grizzly connector

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

Created a super simple ReaderInceptor and registered it with my Jaxrs client using Grizzly as provider. Does not work. Interceptors never seem to get picked up, however Jaxrs filters do.

jersey-grizzly-connector 2.33

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(MyInterceptor.class);
clientConfig.connectorProvider(new GrizzlyConnectorProvider());
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

```
public class MyInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {
    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        System.out.println("here i am");
        return context.proceed();

    }
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. ReaderInterceptor is for inbound requests. Can you provide a complete runnable example?

Comment: Sorry, I meant inbound _responses_ for clients.